# cURL command not returning data or error messages

Tags: bash, api, curl

Figuring out a new API.

I’m trying to call an endpoint and populate a JSON file with the data. I see the following output:

```
admin@server:~$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <NOT DISPLAYED FOR THIS POST>" -o /home/admin/result.json https://www.endpoint.com/manage/query/run?id=55408&cmd=service&output=json
[1] 14493
[2] 14494
admin@server:~$   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

It hangs here seemingly indefinitely until I hit enter and then the below displays

```
[1]-  Done        curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <NOT DISPLAYED FOR THIS POST>" -o /home/admin/result.json https://www.endpoint.com/manage/query/run?id=55408
[2]+  Done        cmd=service
```

No error messages, and no data in result.json. Calling the same cURL command without the -o option also returns the same results, when normally I would expect to see the data pop up in my terminal. If I visit the endpoint URL in browser (auth token can be a URL parameter as well for this API), I see the exact data I want to download. Changing the Auth Token makes no difference in the output.

I know every API is different, and there are a hundred different troubleshooting questions I haven't addressed in this post, but has anyone experienced this type of output before with a cURL command? I've never seen this behavior before.

The API is for Slate, an SIS for universities, if that helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL has a `&` in it which is a bash syntax character to run a task in the background. Quote the URL to prevent it being interpreted as syntax.

```
admin@server:~$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <NOT DISPLAYED FOR THIS POST>" -o /home/admin/result.json "https://www.endpoint.com/manage/query/run?id=55408&cmd=service&output=json"
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. I was hoping it was something simple like that. Thank you so much!